# How can I have the applications listed on an application menu be invoked on a remote system?

Tags: lubuntu, menu, remote, openbox

I can invoke an application via a command line in a terminal emulator:

```
$ ssh -X rome xeyes
```

I can also invoke an application from a GUI application menu on a panel. I can have two GUI application menus on a panel.

How can I have all of the applications listed on the second application menu be invoked on a remote system rather than having to use the terminal emulator?

Comment: Have you looked at vnc forwarding?

Comment: I agree, for what you want, VNC is better then ssh. I advise FreeNX as it is secure and fast.